# How I can access the selected text in IE11 from context menu, and copy to Clipboard

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, contextmenu

I have tried anything to get the selected text for a context menu, but it is not working in IE11.
For context menu adding I have added some code in registry, and a htm file with a Javascript.
First I have tried this:

```
var parentwin = external.menuArguments;
var doc = parentwin.document;
var sel = doc.selection;
var rng  = sel.createRange();
var selectedtext = new String(rng.text);
```

then I have read in IE11 documentation, the document.selection has been repalced in the API with window.getSelection();

So I have tried any variant, window.getSelection... nothing works...

Any idea how I can access the selected text?

And I have searching also how I can copy to the clipboard.. in chrome I have used this script:

```
function copyToClipboard(text){
 var copyDiv = document.createElement('div');
 copyDiv.contentEditable = true;
 document.body.appendChild(copyDiv);
 copyDiv.innerHTML = text;
 copyDiv.unselectable = "off";
 copyDiv.focus();
 document.execCommand('SelectAll');
 document.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
 document.body.removeChild(copyDiv);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the solution:  (tested in IE11)

```
var parentwin = external.menuArguments
var selectedText = getSel();                

function getSel(){
  var w=window,d=parentwin.document,gS='getSelection';
  return (''+(w[gS]?w[gS]():d[gS]?d[gS]():d.selection.createRange().text)).replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,'');
}

parentwin.console.log("the selected text is:"+sel);
copyToClipboard(selectedText);


function copyToClipboard(s) {           //only works in IE :(
if (window.clipboardData && clipboardData.setData) {
    clipboardData.setData('text', s);
}
}
```